# is it possible to keep my dev environment but show all the error n save the logs on symfony 1.4?

Tags: symfony-1.4

Ive been trying to to set correctly the test environment on symfony 1.4 but not success, I was wondering if is any way to make symfony show the errors or log them.

What I tried to make my test env was on my index.php file of symfony/web/ I set this

```
$configuration = ProjectConfiguration::getApplicationConfiguration('orangehrm', 'test', true);
```

I have the logs enabled, but still what I only see when I get an error is "An internal error occurred. Please contact your system administrator. "  Any idea?

I am working with symfony 1.4

My apache log file is also empty.

Comment: Are you sure your apache log is empty? Which operating system are you using?

Comment: I am using linux debian dist version 6... all logs are empty.. even the logs of the project

Answer (score 0):

In the config settings file (/apps/frontend/config/settings.yml), you must enable error_reporting and web_debug parameters for your "test" environment. For example :

```
test:
  .settings:
    error_reporting:        <?php echo (E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED)."\n" ?>
    web_debug:              true
    cache:                  false
    no_script_name:         false
    etag:                   false
```